# Javascript 30 course in react

Tags: reactjs, jsx

Hello i dont understand why i get a error here.
The error is a Unexpected token, expected "," (33:8)
can someone help me to why this happens?

i also tried to put the code inside the body of the return statement but i gave the same error for both const (line 32) and keys.

```
import React from 'react'; <br>
import Clap from './sounds/clap.wav'; <br>
import Hihat from './sounds/hihat.wav'; <br>
import Kick from './sounds/kick.wav'; <br>
import Openhat from './sounds/openhat.wav'; <br>
import Boom from './sounds/boom.wav'; <br>
import Ride from './sounds/ride.wav'; <br>
import Snare from './sounds/snare.wav'; <br>
import Tom from './sounds/tom.wav'; <br>
import Tink from './sounds/tink.wav'; <br>

import './Drumkit.css';

const Drumkit = () => {
    
    window.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
        const audio = document.querySelector(`audio[data-key="${e.keyCode}"]`);
        const key = document.querySelector(`.key[data-key="${e.keyCode}"]`);
        if (!audio) return;
        audio.currentTime = 0;
        audio.play();
        key.classList.add('playing');
        })
    

    
        function removeTransition(e) {
            if(e.propertyName !== 'transform') return;
            this.classList.remove('playing');
        }

        const keys = ( document.querySelectorAll('.key')
        keys.forEach(key => key.addEventListener('transitionend', removeTransition))
        window.addEventListener('keydown', playSound)
    

    
    
    

    return (
            <body>

                <div class="keys">
                    <div data-key="65" class="key">
                        <kbd>A </kbd>
                        <span class="sound">clap</span>
                    </div>
                    <div data-key="83" class="key">
                        <kbd>S</kbd>
                        <span class="sound">hihat</span>
                    </div>
                    <div data-key="68" class="key">
                        <kbd>D</kbd>
                        <span class="sound">kick</span>
                    </div>
                    <div data-key="70" class="key">
                        <kbd>F</kbd>
                        <span class="sound">openhat</span>
                    </div>
                    <div data-key="71" class="key">
                        <kbd>G</kbd>
                        <span class="sound">boom</span>
                    </div>
                    <div data-key="72" class="key">
                        <kbd>H</kbd>
                        <span class="sound">ride</span>
                    </div>
                    <div data-key="74" class="key">
                        <kbd>J</kbd>
                        <span class="sound">snare</span>
                    </div>
                    <div data-key="75" class="key">
                        <kbd>K</kbd>
                        <span class="sound">tom</span>
                    </div>
                    <div data-key="76" class="key">
                        <kbd>L</kbd>
                        <span class="sound">tink</span>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <audio data-key="65" src={Clap}></audio>
                <audio data-key="83" src={Hihat}></audio>
                <audio data-key="68" src={Kick}></audio>
                <audio data-key="70" src={Openhat}></audio>
                <audio data-key="71" src={Boom}></audio>
                <audio data-key="72" src={Ride}></audio>
                <audio data-key="74" src={Snare}></audio>
                <audio data-key="75" src={Tom}></audio>
                <audio data-key="76" src={Tink}></audio>

            </body>
        )
}

export default Drumkit;
```

Comment: are you missing a closing paren on line 32?  Or extraneous open paren?

Comment: The opening parenthesis on this line seems unnecessary: `const keys = ( document.querySelectorAll('.key')`. Perhaps should be `const keys = document.querySelectorAll('.key')`. You may be missing some parenthesis/curly braces near the end the function as well.

Comment: omg im stupid :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This part of the code seems of

```
const keys = ( document.querySelectorAll('.key')
```

Try changing it for this:

```
const keys = document.querySelectorAll('.key')

keys.forEach(key => key.addEventListener(
    'transitionend',
    removeTransition
))

window.addEventListener('keydown', playSound)
```

i Think that is your problem, if not try adding brackets to the if statements, simplified ifs tend to be problematic if not used correctly

```
if(e.propertyName !== 'transform'){
    return;
}
```